JsonConverterAttribute is not used by JsonSerializer
I am trying to serialize a property of Encoding type. I wrote a converter class for that purpose. When I use JsonSerializerOptions everything works, but when I use JsonConverterAttribute I get an exception. I am not sure what I am doing wrong to use JsonConverterAttribute so I hope for your help.
Example code and exceptions:
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace TestJsonConverterBug
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options = new();

        static void Main()
        {
            _options.Converters.Add(new JsonEncodingConverter());

            TestOptions();
            TestAttributeSerialize();
            TestAttributeDeserialize();
        }

        // WORKS WITH OPTIONS
        static void TestOptions()
        {
            var obj = new SerializableClass1();

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, _options);

            var enc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SerializableClass1>(json, _options);
        }

        // DOESN'T WORK WITH CONVERTER ATTRIBUTE
        static void TestAttributeSerialize()
        {
            var obj = new SerializableClass2();

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
        }

        // DOESN'T WORK WITH CONVERTER ATTRIBUTE
        static void TestAttributeDeserialize()
        {
            var obj = new SerializableClass2();

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, _options);

            var enc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SerializableClass2>(json);
        }
    }

    internal class SerializableClass1
    {
        public SerializableClass1()
        {
            Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        }

        public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }
    }

    internal class SerializableClass2
    {
        public SerializableClass2()
        {
            Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonEncodingConverter))]
        public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }
    }

    internal class JsonEncodingConverter : JsonConverter<Encoding>
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
            => typeToConvert.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Encoding));

        public override Encoding? Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options
        ) => Encoding.GetEncoding(reader.GetString()!);

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Encoding value,
            JsonSerializerOptions options
        ) => writer.WriteStringValue(value.EncodingName);
    }
}

TestAttributeSerialize exception:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The type 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1[System.Byte]' of property 'Preamble' on type 'System.Text.Encoding' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.
  Source=System.Text.Json
  StackTrace:
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_CannotSerializeInvalidType(Type typeToConvert, Type declaringType, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreatePropertyInfo(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo, Type typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean shouldCheckForRequiredKeyword, Boolean hasJsonIncludeAttribute)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.AddMembersDeclaredBySuperType(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo, Type currentType, Boolean constructorHasSetsRequiredMembersAttribute, PropertyHierarchyResolutionState& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.PopulateProperties(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreateTypeInfoCore(Type type, JsonConverter converter, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoNoCaching(Type type)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.CachingContext.CreateCacheEntry(Type type, CachingContext context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(Type type, Boolean ensureConfigured, Nullable`1 ensureNotNull, Boolean resolveIfMutable, Boolean fallBackToNearestAncestorType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo.Configure()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.ConfigureProperties()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.Configure()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(Type type, Boolean ensureConfigured, Nullable`1 ensureNotNull, Boolean resolveIfMutable, Boolean fallBackToNearestAncestorType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoForRootType(Type type, Boolean fallBackToNearestAncestorType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.GetTypeInfo[T](JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at TestJsonConverterBug.Program.TestAttributeSerialize() in ...\TestJsonConverterBug\Program.cs:line 35
   at TestJsonConverterBug.Program.Main() in ...\TestJsonConverterBug\Program.cs:line 16

TestAttributeDeserialize exception:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The type 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1[System.Byte]' of property 'Preamble' on type 'System.Text.Encoding' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.
  Source=System.Text.Json
  StackTrace:
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_CannotSerializeInvalidType(Type typeToConvert, Type declaringType, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreatePropertyInfo(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo, Type typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean shouldCheckForRequiredKeyword, Boolean hasJsonIncludeAttribute)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.AddMembersDeclaredBySuperType(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo, Type currentType, Boolean constructorHasSetsRequiredMembersAttribute, PropertyHierarchyResolutionState& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.PopulateProperties(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.CreateTypeInfoCore(Type type, JsonConverter converter, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoNoCaching(Type type)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.CachingContext.CreateCacheEntry(Type type, CachingContext context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(Type type, Boolean ensureConfigured, Nullable`1 ensureNotNull, Boolean resolveIfMutable, Boolean fallBackToNearestAncestorType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo.Configure()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.ConfigureProperties()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.Configure()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoInternal(Type type, Boolean ensureConfigured, Nullable`1 ensureNotNull, Boolean resolveIfMutable, Boolean fallBackToNearestAncestorType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetTypeInfoForRootType(Type type, Boolean fallBackToNearestAncestorType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.GetTypeInfo[T](JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at TestJsonConverterBug.Program.TestAttributeDeserialize() in ...\TestJsonConverterBug\Program.cs:line 45
   at TestJsonConverterBug.Program.Main() in ...\TestJsonConverterBug\Program.cs:line 17


Related GitHub issue: Behavior difference in JsonSerializer between .NET7 and .NET8 p4 #86419

@YongShun, I saw this issue. The issue is about that Encoding cannot be serialized as-is. In the issue discussion it's suggested to use JsonConverter, but I already do use JsonConverter.

This is a regression in .NET 8 that has already been reported. See Allow specifying JsonConverter attribute annotations on properties of unsupported type. #95893 and System.Text.Json.Serialization: Converter from attribute is ignored #97803.

This is a known regression in .NET 8 which has already been reported. See:

Allow specifying JsonConverter attribute annotations on properties of unsupported type. #95893
System.Text.Json.Serialization: Converter from attribute is ignored #97803.

It seems to be an unintended(?) side effect of the intentional breaking change noted in [Breaking change]: The System.Text.Json reflection-based deserializer is resolving all property metadata eagerly #37041.  In that issue, MSFT's Eirik Tsarpalis  recommends:

Removing the unsupported property, authoring a custom converter for the unsupported type, or adding the JsonIgnoreAttribute like so...

Since adding a converter does not work, you can instead mark the Encoding property with [JsonIgnore] and add a surrogate string property with the encoding name:
internal class SerializableClass2
{
    public SerializableClass2()
    {
        Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    }

    [JsonInclude, JsonPropertyName("Encoding")]
    string EncodingName { get => Encoding?.EncodingName!; set => Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(value); }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }
}

The surrogate can be private as long as it is marked with [JsonInclude].
Demo fiddle here.

So... The Encoding-object is not really serializeable...
It will probably happen that you do not have control over the class that contains an Encoding property, like in my case.
You may not even be aware of that an object in the inheritance-chain of what you are returning hides an Encoding-object.
So, as a standard, I recommend the following to prevent future problems and surprises, as your application grows.
The simple solution is to add the following class
public class EncodingConverter : JsonConverter<System.Text.Encoding>
{
    public override System.Text.Encoding Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string encodingName = reader.GetString();
        return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encodingName);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, System.Text.Encoding value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.WebName);
    }
}

And in startup or program.cs, just add
        services
        .AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
        {
            opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EncodingConverter());
        });

Enjoy NET8 with one less bad surprise :-)
